# Getting Facebook GraphMethodException on server but not localhost

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm building a MEAN app and I'm trying to get some data about a FB page with following Graph API request:

https://graph.facebook.com/153572758009832?fields=name,description,picture.type(large),location,phone,emails&access_token=MyAppId|MyAppSecret

This works correctly on localhost, but fails on live server with the following response:

```
{"error":
    {"message":
        "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https:\/\/developers.facebook.com\/docs\/graph-api","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"GqwXhNwvjIJ"
    }
}
```

I've also tried to obtain the access_token for my app, and use it instead of app id|secret pair, and also to use [the following FB SDK for node](https://github.com/Thuzi/facebook-node-sdk), but with the same result. I've thought maybe FB has some server IP address restrictions for apps, but could find nothing.

Comment: As this is a page for a bar/club, it is probably access restricted – for alcohol-related content, or by age. And as such you can not request information about it using your app access token – you need to use a page access token for that page, or a user access token for a user that qualifies to see the content. It should not have worked on your localhost either with an app access token – did you actually get any data, or do you just have error message suppressed there …?

Comment: I'm getting the actual page data on my localhost - the proper name, description, place, etc. I've opened an issue at facebook and they have suggested that because both my localhost and the page from request are situated in same country, the call worked, but the production server is in another country, so the call is not allowed from it to that page. But, I have tried to request pages from another countries from my localhost, and they again return valid responses.

Comment: Pretty sure the API does not care what country your server is in. That should come into play only when using user access tokens, not app tokens. Can you link to the bug report (assuming that it is public)? Are you in control of the page? If so, does it actually have country-based restrictions set?

Comment: Seems you are right - the owner of the page has restricted the page for some countries. I've created a fake page, restricted it from my country and got the error from localhost. So, alas, no magic for localhost :) it is a country restriction. Thank you for your help.